# How do I get data from firebase realtime databese with React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to get a data firebase realtime database. I can show data with console.log() but I cannot show in Flat list. I tried different ways to solve this problem. But, I could not find any certain solution.
Here, my JSON tree in firebase:

[image: json tree]

Here, my code:

```js
const NotesList = (props) => {

  const { colors } = useTheme();
  const styles = customStyles(colors);

  const user = auth().currentUser
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const getData = () => {
    firebase.database().ref(`notes/`).on('value', function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setData(getData);
      setLoading(true);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ marginRight: 10, marginLeft: 10 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <NoteCard title={item.noteTitle} icerik={item.noteDetails} date={item.timestamp} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
  const split = () => {
    let icerik = data.map((item, key) => item.icerik);
    return icerik.slice(0, 1) + '...';
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      
      <NoteSearchBar />
      {!loading ? (
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <ActivityIndicator color="#ff5227" />
        </View>
      ) : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            numColumns={2}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          />
        )}
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.addButton}
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('AddNote')}>
        <Plus width={40} height={40} fill="white" margin={10} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I tried many different ways, but no suggestions solved the problem. I would be glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution and I want to share it with you guys.
I kept the data from firebase as a child at a new value, then I put it in setData. In this way, I can display the data in the flat list.

```
 const getData = () => {
firebase.database().ref(`notes/`).on('value', snapshot => {
    let responselist = Object.values(snapshot.val())
    setData(responselist)
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    setLoading(true);
});
}

useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);
```

Also, while firebase realtime DB was working, a new method called Object method helped when taking child values in the JSON tree.

Comment: As I said in my answer, here too you call `setData` in the callback for `on('value'`. While it's possible your original post had multiple problems, it's common to acknowledge when you use somebody's answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData` doesn't **return** the data, as the data is loaded asynchronously. You should instead move he call to `setData` into your `getData`:

```
  const getData = () => {
    firebase.database().ref(`notes/`).on('value', function (snapshot) {
      setData(snapshot.val());
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      getData()
      setLoading(true);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

Now the call to `setData` will put the JSON into the state, which in turn forces React to repaint the UI with the new data.

Comment: Hi Frank, I tried your suggestion, but still have the same issue, and I got an index range error when we do this. As I mentioned, I can see the data in the console, but I cannot show it in the list.

Comment: None of the code in my answer accesses anything with a range, so if you now get that error it is likely coming from code you already had. In fact, I expect this to be a good sign, as it likely means your rendering code is now getting invoked with the data from the database, and the error comes from code that wasn't being called before.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, basically you made 2 mistake:

1. `getData` does not return nothing so data will be never updated with values from firebase;
2. `useEffect` has a strange implementation (it's useless call `setTimeout` you are already waiting data from firebase);

My suggestion is to call `getData` from `useEffect` like this:

```
   useEffect(() => {
      getData()
   }, []);
```

And modify `getData` like this:

```
    const getData = () => {
       firebase.database().ref(`notes/`).on('value', function (snapshot) {
          setData(snapshot.val());
          setLoading(true);
       });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Gio, I tried your suggestion, but still have the same issue, and I got an index range error when we do this. As I mentioned, I can see the data in the console, but I cannot show it in the list. It's a similar result with Frank's.

Comment: Ciao, I tried to reproduce your NotesList in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-gucwd?file=/src/index.js) codesendbox. It's almost equal (except for NoteSearchBar, NoteCard and data). As you can see, FlatList is visible with correct data. Supposing that NoteSearchBar and data are not the problem, maybe NoteCard is failing... I don't know, what do you think?